# Finding the inverse of $(x^2+2)$ in the field $S = \Bbb F_3[x]/(x^4+x^3+x^2+1)$

Tags: finite-fields, euclidean-algorithm, polynomial-rings

Let $S = \Bbb F_3[x]/(x^4+x^3+x^2+1)$.

Find the inverse of $(x^2+2)$ in $S$.

I know I'm looking for a polynomial $q(x)$ such that $(x^2+2)q(x) = 1 \mod x^4+x^3+x^2+1$

i.e $(x^2+2)q(x) + k(x)(x^4+x^3+x^2+1) = 1$ for some $k(x)$ in $\Bbb F_3[x]$

I'm not really sure how to find $q(x), k(x)$. I understand the Euclidean algorithm (in polynomials) needs to be applied, but I'm not really sure how to do this working over $\Bbb F_3[x]$.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb F_3[x]/(x^4+x^3+x^2+1)?$ Because `\setminus` means something different, and there is no inverse there.

Comment: Yes, sorry! Wasn't sure on the notation. I'll edit it now.

Comment: The same algorithm that works for integer works for polynomials over a field, because polynomials over a field are Euclidean domains.

Answer (score 2):

In $\mathbb F_3[x]$, you could replace $x^2+2$ with $x^2-1$.

$$\color{purple}{x^4+x^3+x^2+1}=(\color{blue}{x^2-1})(x^2+x-1)+\color{green}x$$

$$\color{blue}{x^2-1}=x(\color{green}x)-\color{orange}1$$

So $$\color{orange}1=x[\color{green}x]-(\color{blue}{x^2-1})=x\left[\color{green}{x^4+x^3+x^2+1-( {x^2-1})(x^2+x-1)}\right]-(\color{blue}{x^2-1}) $$

$$=x(\color{purple}{x^4+x^3+x^2+1})\color{red}{-(x^3+x^2-x+1)}(x^2-1),$$

so an inverse of $x^2-1$ in $\mathbb F_3[x]/(\color{purple}{x^4+x^3+x^2+1})$

is $\color{red}{-(x^3+x^2-x+1)\equiv2x^3+2x^2+x+2}.$

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation. How did you know to replace $x^2+2$ with $x^2-1$ / what trick is used to notice that kind of pattern in similar problems?

Comment: $2\equiv-1\pmod3$, and I thought that replacement would make the calculations easier